# Using IValidatableObject to check if at-least one parameter is set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an `UpdateAccountRequest` object that represents a `PUT` request body to update an existing `Account` object. Currently, the only property that can be updated using this endpoint is the `Disabled` property. To make sure the caller did not send an empty `UpdateAccountRequest` request, I'm using the `IValidateObject` interface like so:

```
public class UpdateAccountRequest: IValidatableObject
{
    public bool? Disabled { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!Disabled.HasValue)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Disabled must be set");
        }
    }
}
```

However, in the future, I'm planning to add more properties to this class and I want to make a generic method to validate that the caller specified at-least **one** update property. I can use reflection to achieve this by going over all of the instance's properties and check their type and see if they are not null, but I was wondering if there's something in the framework to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with something like this. Not my proudest creation, but it seems to work. Not sure if the framework has support for something like this out-of-the-box.

```
public class UpdateAccountRequest: IValidatableObject
{
    public bool? Disabled { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var satisfiedMembers = this.GetType().GetProperties()
                          .Select(prop => prop.GetValue(this, null))
                          .Where(val => val != null);
            
        if (!satisfiedMembers.Any())
        {
                yield return new ValidationResult("At-least one update parameter must be supplied");
        }
    }
}
```